# How do I find libpython2.6.so.1.0 for CentOS 5.0?

Tags: centos

I searched rpmfind.net under CentOS and [couldn't find it](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libpython2.6.so.1.0&submit=Search%20...&system=centos&arch=).

But python-libs 2.4.3-46.el5_8.2 is already installed on my server

Comment: Really? CentOS 5.0? Not 5.1, 5.4, 5.8?

Answer (score 3):

```
# yum provides *libpython2.6*
...
python26-libs-2.6.8-1.el5.x86_64 : The libraries for python runtime
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
Other       : libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't find it. But, you can always compile it yourself.

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.8/Python-2.6.8.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.6.7.tgz
./configure --prefix=/opt/python2.6 --with-threads --enable-shared --with-zlib=/usr/include
make && make install

sudo ln -s /opt/python2.6/lib/libpython2.6.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /opt/python2.6/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 /usr/lib
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
sudo ln -s /opt/python2.6/bin/python /usr/local/python
```

You can now check the version with `python -V`.

You also might want to check if `yum` is still working, because that's usually the first to go when you start playing with python versions.

The above lines come from an install script I use and assume you build everything in `/opt`

Answer (score 2):

If you really need Python 2.6 on your old CentOS 5 box, you can use the [python26 packages](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Python26) provided by [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).